# Converting XSD files to Ruby classes

Tags: ruby, xml, xsd

I am planning to convert a large amount of XSD documents to Ruby classes and it is very tiresome to do it by hand. I would like to find an automated way of doing this instead.

I have found a gem called rxsd (https://github.com/movitto/RXSD) but it doesn't  work (it only generates empty classes). However, it does have some infrastructure that might be worth building on.

We are currently using libxml for parsing the schema files which is documented here https://xml4r.github.io/libxml-ruby/rdoc/

Any suggestions? Has anyone had to do this before?

Comment: I am also in the same situation.  I'm debating on whether or not I want to try and fix the RXSD gem or try a different path.  Did you ever make any progress on this issue?

Comment: I'm afraid we just made them by hand. The RXSD gem shows promise though. Wish I had more time for it.